# Difference between raise Exception, "foo" and raise Exception("foo")?

Tags: python

The title is pretty self explanatory -- what's the difference between:

```
raise Exception, "foo"
```

and

```
raise Exception("foo")
```

Does it do exactly the same thing, just different syntax?

I'm using Python 2.x, but I'd like to hear of any differences in Python 3.x

Comment: When you tried it, what did you observe?

Comment: @bradley.ayers: Okay.  So what's the question, then?

Comment: I don't assume that because I see no discernible difference, that there *is* no difference. I think my question is fairly clear, which part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @bradley.ayers: If you checked `dir()` and `type()` and saw no differences, it's hard for me to imagine what difference you were hoping  might secretly be hidden somewhere.  Can you explain what secret, mysterious or hidden difference you think might exist.  I'm sorry that I do not share your pessimism about this, but I can't understand what cryptic differences might possibly exist when the two constructs appear the same.  Can you provide an example of two things which appear the same but aren't the same?

Comment: Perhaps the difference between ABC://google.com and abc://google.com both work fine, but the former is incorrect according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt (Section 3.1) -- however note that it suggests programs should treat them as equivalent. In this sense for all intents and purposes they *seem* the same, but there *is* a difference, one violates the RFC, and the other doesn't.

Comment: @bradley.ayers: Since both work in Python, neither violates the Python syntax.  I'm still unclear on what you're asking for.  Do you want someone to check PEP8 for you?

Comment: You should be able to see that someone's already answered this question. I have accepted that answer, and so by reading that answer you will be able to see what I considered to be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @bradley.ayers: Sorry.  I'm unable to discern what you didn't know and how that provided the information you lacked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname is another good example

Answer (score 25, accepted):

both amount to the same thing in Python2. in Python3, the `raise Exception, "foo"` syntax is no longer supported.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, that `raise Exception, ('foo', 'bar')` is equivalent to `raise Exception('foo', 'bar')`