# Why does Python raise with arguments needs unpacking?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

In this code the exception that is raised is the one described by the tuple exc_info returns.

```
from sys import exc_info
a, b, c = exc_info()
raise a, b, c
```

In the next code the exception that is raised is a new one and not the one from exc_info

```
from sys import exc_info
raise exc_info()
```

The difference is only the unpacking of the tuple, why is sending "a, b, c" not a tuple? (as it usually would be)
What's going on here?

Using 2.7

Answer (score 1):

That's because `raise a,b,traceback` means `raise a(b)` using `traceback`'s line numbers in Python 2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448229/difference-between-raise-exception-foo-and-raise-exceptionfoo) and the [`raise` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt). `raise (a,b,c)` is different; it raises a tuple consisting of `a`, `b`, and `c`.